# Replace string with regular expression and my own parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

In my html I've serval token like this:

```
{PROP_1_1}, {PROP_1_2}, {PROP_37871_1} ...
```

Actually I replace that token with the following code:

```
htmlBuffer = htmlBuffer.Replace("{PROP_" + prop.PropertyID + "_1}", prop.PropertyDefaultHtml);
```

where **prop** is a custom object. But in this case it affects only the tokens ending with '_1'. I would like to propagate this logic to all the rest ending up with '_X' where X is numeric.
How could I implement a regexp pattern to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Replace()`:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("{PROP_" + prop.PropertyID + "_\d+}");
htmlBuffer = rgx.Replace(htmlBuffer, prop.PropertyDefaultHtml);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do even better, you can catch both identifiers in a regular expression. That way you can loop through the references that exist in the string and get the properties for those, instead of looping through all the properties that you have and check if there is any reference for them in the string.

Example:

```
htmlBuffer = Regex.Replace(htmlBuffer, @"{PROP_(\d+)_(\d+)}", m => {
  int id = Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
  int suffix = Int32.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value);
  return properties[id].GetValue(suffix);
});
```